# Text processing - Replace second from start and second from end per line

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have bad csv files, and need to add some quotes

In

```
field,field2,text field with potential commas,field4,field5
field,field2,text fie,ld with pot,ential commas,field4,field5
field,field2,text field with, potential commas,field4,field5
```

Out

```
field,field2,"text field with potential commas",field4,field5
field,field2,"text fie,ld with pot,ential commas",field4,field5
field,field2,"text field with, potential commas",field4,field5
```

`sed 's/,/,"/2'` will add the first quote, but how can I do the same with the second occurence backwards from the end, for each line?

sed, awk, perl and other methods are welcome. Files are some million lines, speed is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an `awk` way: if there are more than five comma-delimited fields, then loop through the "middle" fields concatenating them before printing the new field surrounded by quotes, followed by the final two fields:

```
awk -f awkscript.awk < input
```

With the following as the `awkscript.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
  OFS=","
  FS=","
}
{
        if (NF > 5) {
                middle=""
                for(i=3; i <= NF-2; i++)
                        middle=(middle ? middle"," : "")$i
                print $1, $2, "\""middle"\"", $(NF-1), $NF
        } else {
                print $1, $2, "\""$3"\"", $4, $5
        }
}
```

Comment: If you have the awk code in a file, I'd recommend you add `FS=","` to the BEGIN block, in case you forget to `-F,` -- or rather, so you don't need to remember it.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, glenn. Also because it will run fine on my windows. (Windows doesn't like the -F parameter)

Comment: So incorporated!

Comment: Info: this is ~200% faster than the sed solution, for my files.

Comment: Simpler: `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$3="\""$3;$(NF-2)=$(NF-2)"\"";print}` (and also safe if any field 3 happens to be `0`)

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` you would do:

```
sed 's/,/,"/2; s/\(,[^,]*,[^,]*\)$/"\1/' infile
```

This `s/,/,"/2` replaces only second one.
This `s/\(,[^,]*,[^,]*\)$` matches `,anything-not-a-comma,anything-not-a-comma` from the end `$` of line as a group match with back-reference of `\1`, then in replacement part after adding a quote we bring it back `"\1`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a stupidly simple approach, though probably not the most efficient:

```
sed 's/,/,"/2' input.csv | rev | sed 's/,/,"/2' | rev > output.csv
```

Comment: Brilliant.  The only solution here I understand by glancing at.

Answer (score 2):

perl: This version quotes all the fields, and handles any "interior" quotes

```
$ cat file
field,field2,text field with potential commas,field4,field5
field,field2,text fie,ld with pot,ential commas,field4,field5
field,field2,text field with, potential commas,field4,field5
field,field2,"Just drive," she said,f4,f5

$ perl -F, -lane '
    @result = ( splice(@F,0,2), undef, splice(@F,@F-2,2) );
    $result[2] = join ",", @F;
    print join ",", map {s/"/""/g; qq/"$_"/} @result
' file 

"field","field2","text field with potential commas","field4","field5"
"field","field2","text fie,ld with pot,ential commas","field4","field5"
"field","field2","text field with, potential commas","field4","field5"
"field","field2","""Just drive,"" she said","f4","f5"
```

The first line of code extracts the first 2 and last 2 data fields.
The second line collects all the rest of the data as the 3rd field.
The third line outputs as CSV.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '
   s/,/&\n/2
   s/\n\(.*\)\(,.*,.*\)/"\1"\2/
'    input.csv


 perl -pe '
    my $p;
    while ( /,/g ) {
       s/\G/"/,next if ++$p == 2;

       last if s/,\G(?=.*,)(?!.*,.*,)/",/;  # looks for 2nd last comma
    }
 '    input-file.csv



 perl -pe '
      substr($_, index($_, q/,/, 1+index($_, q/,/)), 1) = q/,"/;

      substr($_, rindex($_, q/,/, -1+rindex($_, q/,/)), 1) = q/",/;
 '     csvfile
```

Here we invoke the index function twice to get the position of second comma from the left. Then place a quote mark adjacent to it using the substr function now that the position has been ascertained.

Similarly, we invoke the rindex function and do the corresponding change.